# Heroku : build failed

Tags: angular, heroku, npm

I am facing an heroku problem : **my build fails and I have no reason provided**.

Until now, I had no problem to deploy. On my locale machine, I too have no problem to deploy.

But on my heroku app, the build stops and tells me this :

`ERROR in ./src/main.ts
       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/tmp/build_098d2d84d2c08a7fa3bef316a8cd94a1/username-appName-91dd9c8/src'
       @ ./src/main.ts 4:0-74
       @ multi ./src/main.ts`

I have made no update to my package.json, simply changed some code in my project. And since I'm a free user, I don't think I can contact heroku to get more help.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a known Angular CLI bug. Upgrading the version to the latest one fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your details on your build, one reason may be the heroku build is doing a --prod build and locally you are not. The prod build is much more strict. If this is the issue, do ng serve -o --prod locally and see if it fails and it will give you a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I use a command for internationalization, meaning I run a command that run multiple languages. The same commands are launched on locale machine and heroku, and yes they use AOT along with prod mode. This is why it's strange, the only difference between locale and heroku is the OS